# How to insert items in list of item without a lot of iterations

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a dataClass, which contains a unique `code` of item, code of the parent and two lists - `categories` and `subcategories`.

```
data class MyItem (
        var code: String,
        var name: String,*
        var data: String,
        var count: Int,
        var parent: String,
        var categories: MutableList<MyItem>,
        var subcategories: MutableList<MyItem>
)
```

I've got from server 3 different items list. And structure that I want to get is:

```
- listOfTopLevelItems
--- listOfMiddleLevelItems
----- listOfBottomLevelItems
```

where every topLevelItem contains a list of middleLevelItems and every middle level items contains a list of bottom level items. For that i used code below

```
                for (topItem in topLevelItems) {
                    for (middleItem in middleLevelItems) {
                        if (topItem.code == middleItem.parent) {
                            val middleResultItem = middleItem

                            for (bottomItem in bottomLevelItems) {
                                if (middleItem.code == bottomItem.parent) {
                                    middleResultItem.subcategories.add(bottomItem)
                                }
                            }

                            topItem.categories.add(middleResultItem)
                        }
                    }

                    result.add(topItem)
                }
```

But the problem is if i will have a lots of items on bottom level, than it will be a lot of iterations. Is there is another way to solve this?

Comment: Use Gson or any parsing lib. it will parse your json into model without any iteration.

Comment: @HemantParmar what does Gson have to do with it? The question doesn't even mention JSON.

Answer (score 0):

So what you have is a DAG of depth 3. I am going to make some other adjustments other than just solving your iteration problem.

First, I think the structure of your data classes is a bit redundant for describing a graph of objects. You do not need the category and subcategory fields in my opinion. Stripping out the irrelevant fields, this is what mine would look like:

```
data class MyItem(
        var code: String,
        var parent: String? = null,
        var categories: MutableList<MyItem> = mutableListOf()
){
    val subcategories: List<MyItem>
        get() = categories.flatMap { it.categories }

}
```

A root/top item will be any item where the parent is null. And then its categories are its immediate children, and its sub categories are its grandchildren. I have provided a property here which will take care of grandchildren if you really want that accessor, and it means if you add something to a child, the parents grandchildren will be updated automatically :D.

Now for version 1 of creating the object graph. This keeps things in line with your apparent structure of knowing which ones are roots, children and grand children. But this is not needed as you will see in version 2.

```
fun main() {
    val topItems = listOf(MyItem("1"), MyItem("2"))
    val middleItems = listOf(MyItem("1_1", "1"), MyItem("1_2", "1"), MyItem("2_1", "2"))
    val bottomItems = listOf(MyItem("1_1_1", "1_1"), MyItem("1_2_1", "1_2"), MyItem("2_1_1", "2_1"))

    val topByID = topItems.map { it.code to it }.toMap()
    val middleByID = middleItems.map { it.code to it }.toMap()

    bottomItems.forEach { middleByID[it.parent]?.categories?.add(it) }
    middleItems.forEach { topByID[it.parent]?.categories?.add(it) }

    println(topItems)
    println(topItems[0].subcategories)
}
```

But really, all you need to know for building an obect graph is parent child relationship, and they can all just be in a big collection. Then you can rebuild your object graph like this:

```
fun main() {
    val topItems = listOf(MyItem("1", "*"), MyItem("2", "*"))
    val middleItems = listOf(MyItem("1_1", "1"), MyItem("1_2", "1"), MyItem("2_1", "2"))
    val bottomItems = listOf(MyItem("1_1_1", "1_1"), MyItem("1_2_1", "1_2"), MyItem("2_1_1", "2_1"))

    val allItems = topItems + middleItems + bottomItems
    val allItemsByID = allItems.map { it.code to it }.toMap()

    allItems.forEach {
        allItemsByID[it.parent]?.categories?.add(it)
    }

    println(topItems)
    println(topItems[0].subcategories)
}
```

This is my favorite approach :D